# How to use and abuse a transformable metal

Tags: science-based, magic, technology, medieval

My dm has given my character a metal that can:
"Be as flexible as linen or more rigid than tungsten. Properties that can be adjusted: tensile strength, torque strength, rigidity, density."

## Im wondering, how do I use and abuse this?

I can easily think of using clothes and then hardening them for armor, or perhaps making some super dense penetrator for a sword tip, but I'm thinking about perhaps using it for some perpetual motion machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. I am afraid you have got our scope wrong. We don't do brainstorming or give ideas. We, as you can read in our [help], solve well defined worldbuilding problems, in other words, problems about the rule of your world.

Comment: Wrap it around someone's face